# Recursively search in all file which contain multiple same pattern in a line

Tags: bash

Apology for not following StackOverflow best practice

What I want to achieve is if suppose

**file1.txt**

```
something blah blah
something blah blah target_pattern blah blah target_pattern
```

**file2.txt**

```
something blah blah
something blah blah target_pattern blah blah
```

**file3.txt**

```
something blah blah
something blah blah target_pattern blah blah target_pattern blah blah target_pattern
```

I want output as

```
file1.txt target_pattern blah blah target_pattern
file3.txt target_pattern blah blah target_pattern blah blah target_pattern
```

Notice file2.txt have target_pattern but not repeated.
If you know how to count "target_pattern" word for each grep search result, that will also work for me.

For example word count:

```
file1.txt 2
file2.txt 1
file3.txt 3
```

what i tried so far is:

```
> cat q.txt    
something blah blah    
something blah blah target_pattern blah blah target_pattern    
> cat w.txt
something blah blah
something blah blah target_pattern blah blah    
>cat e.txt    
something blah blah    
something blah blah target_pattern blah blah target_pattern    
> grep -r "target_pattern" ./*    
./e.txt:something blah blah target_pattern blah blah target_pattern    
./q.txt:something blah blah target_pattern blah blah target_pattern    
./w.txt:something blah blah target_pattern blah blah    
> grep -r "target_pattern" ./*|grep "target_pattern"    
./e.txt:something blah blah target_pattern blah blah target_pattern    
./q.txt:something blah blah target_pattern blah blah target_pattern    
./w.txt:something blah blah target_pattern blah blah    
> grep -r "target_pattern" ./*| wc -w    
20    
> grep -r "target_pattern" ./*| wc -l   
3
```

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please form complete sentences in particular and use the formatting options to separate the example data of your files from the rest of the text. Simple reason is that your question is barely readable.

Comment: ... also show what you have tried so far.  If you know that `wc` can solve your problem then why don't you use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grep for 2 times target_pattern with something (.*) in between:

```
grep -E "target_pattern.*target_pattern" targetpat.txt 
something blah blah target_pattern blah blah target_pattern
something blah blah target_pattern blah blah target_pattern blah blah target_pattern
```

Read about pattern matching/regular expressions to learn more.

Comment: Thank you so much,
Also thanks for suggesting about pattern matching/regular expressions.
It will really improve my skill.